# Getting data from different tables in one statement?

Tags: sql

I have a game, tables look like:

```
// users
user_id | favorite_color

// games
game_id | game_name

// game_participants
id | fk_game_id | fk_user_id
```

I want to get the favorite colors of all users in a particular game. I could do this in several steps, like:

```
// get the game.
Game game =  select * from games where game_id = 'abc';

// get each user's favorite color, one at a time.
for (participants in game) {
    select favorite_color from users where user_id = game.participants[i].id;
}
```

but is there a way to do this in one select statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT favorite_color
FROM games 
    INNER JOIN game_participants on games.game_id = game_participants.fk_game_id
    INNER JOIN users on users.user_id = game_participants.fk_user_id
WHERE game_id = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.favourite_color
FROM game_participants 
    INNER JOIN users ON game_participants.fk_user_id = users.user_id
WHERE fk_game_id = 'abc'
```